# Cannot create Android Emulator with AVD Manager

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm having problems with creating an Emulator from the AVD Manager. The error dialog says

> Failed to pare properties from C:\User\Giti.androud\avd\Emulator.a

How can i fix this?

Comment: You should, at the very least, explain how you obtain this error. Did you try from command line to gain more control ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Eclipse ADT plugin, or attempting to do this yourself?  If using Eclipse, double check that you have the IDE pointing to the proper SDK installation directory, it is not done for you.  Also recall that when you download the android SDK, it comes with very few things, so the AVD manager must be used to download all of the necessary components from their respective repositories.  You can see this if you open the AVD manager and view the installed packages.  Hope this helps.  Posting more information about your installation will be even more helpful as these steps are just the bare minimum to get up and running with Eclipse.  Good Luck.

EDIT:
You didn't mention whether you're using Eclipse or not, so I think it's important to note that it is strongly recommended that you use Eclipse with the ADT plugin, as android binaries are first built by the java compiler and then translated to dalvik binary.  This is just one of many concepts that you'd have to worry about without using Eclipse.

ANOTHER EDIT:
Based on the error message you posted, I'm assuming that it says "Failed to parse properties from C:\User\Giti.androud\avd\Emulator.a".  There should obviously be a "\" between Giti and .android.  I'm not sure if this was your error or if this is exactly what you saw, in which case Eclipse is building the path string incorrectly.  How exactly are you building the AVD?  Are you doing anything special, e.g. setting the resolution, pixel density different?  When you use the AVD manager, it will create two entries under C:\Users\Giti.android\avd\, one of which is a file named .ini and a directory called .avd which contains the system image and some other configuration settings for the virtual device.  I would first recommend double checking that directory to ensure that these files are there and open them up in notepad to view the settings to ensure that nothing appears malformed, e.g. weird spaces or characters appearing in odd places.  Most of the properties you'll see are straightforward enough that you can detect malformation easily.  Please also post the version of Eclipse that you are using.  Are you new to it?  Have you had it installed before and are just now trying to use the ADT plugin?  Eclipse is very useful but can get pretty complicated when using different configurations.

Comment: Yes i am using Eclipse and i checked that the IDE points to the SDK installation directory under Window => Preferences and i also downloaded all the available packages with the AVD manager.

Comment: Granit, please see my comment and explore the directories listed.  Let me know the version of Eclipse that you are using and whether or not you have used it for other projects in the past.  I'm using Helios on Windows 7 with no issues whatsoever.